Getting "related products" to show on front end
I have setup a number of products via admin and added in related products successfully. I have flushed Caches and re-indexed yet my related products do not show on the front end and I have no idea why ?

Make sure product is saleable products. Check below things for assigned products
Product Type : If simple then make sure visiblity is "Catalog,Search"
Website : Assigned in current website or not
Status : Enabled or Not
Visibility: Catalog, Search
Salable Quantity: Product having proper stock or not.

If all above criteria is matching then it should show on PDP.
additionally, run indexing command and make sure your elasticsearch service is enabled and working properly.
Thanks!!
